# How to Use jQuery Cycle Plugin with Navigation Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar, jquery-cycle

I have been wondering how to use the jquery Cycle Plugin as a way to transition and display my content within divs. I thought of making a parent class container, which will hold the divs with the actual content, and then use cycle on the parent class. I read on the documentation about the pagination, but how do I make the pagination my navigation menu? Will I have to just edit the "#nav" id that comes with the Cycle Plugin or can I use the navigation that I already made? I saw another question here about this but didn't understand how it worked.. Each link should correspond to the div that is linked to it, i.e Whenever the About link is clicked, the about div should appear.. Any explanation to get me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Are you looking for this http://takerootdesign.co.uk/blog/web-design/adding-named-navigation-jquery-cycle-gallery

Answer (score 2):

After some messing around and reading the cycle demo's, I discovered it was really simple. I gave my navigation ul the id of #menu, and then just changed the cycle script accordingly. I changed the pager option in the plugin's script to #menu and the pagerAnchorBuilder function return script to '#menu li:eq(' + idx + ') a'

**Navigation and slideshow HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="slideshow">
        <div>
            <h1>Title One</h1>
            <p>Description for title one</p>         
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Title two</h1>
            <p>Description for title two</p>         
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Title Three</h1>
            <p>Description for title three</p>         
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Title Four</h1>
            <p>Description for title four</p>         
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Plugin Script**

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
fx:     'turnDown', 
speed:  'fast', 
timeout: 0, 
pager:  '#menu', 
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    // return selector string for existing anchor 
    return '#menu li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
} 
});
```